# I need to select asp:radiobutton(asp control) while clicking on html table cell

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, asp.net

I have a table with multiple cells each having one asp radio button control:

[image: table]

I want to be able to check/uncheck radio button(which is asp control, not html) when i click anywhere on table cell. I want to write one javascript/jquery function to which i can pass value from td 'onclick' event and then check/uncheck the corresponding radio button present inside that 'td'. Is it possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [onClick of table cell selects radio button inside the cell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36829880/onclick-of-table-cell-selects-radio-button-inside-the-cell)

Comment: No. I tried it. It did not work may be because i have a server control instead of html. @romanoza

Comment: Do you understand my answer? Should I explain further?

Comment: I understood. Your answer helped me in retrieving the Id.. Thanks a lot. @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf

Comment: If your question has been answered correctly, please select the answer as an accepted answer. So other users can see this is an accepted answer.

Comment: No. that is not the exact answer. I wanted to know how to pass id without actually knowing it which i did by using onclick="checkRadioButton(this.children);". This is what I asked for. Your answer helped me after passing id. So I tried to upvote but i could not as  I am a new member. Thank you for helping. @Tony_KiloPapaMikeGolf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why won't this work for you?

```
<td id="td1" onclick="checkRadioButton($('#<%=rdnQ10aOption1.ClientID%>'));" >
     <asp:RadioButton ID="rdnQ10aOption1" runat="server" GroupName="Q10a"  />
</td>

function checkRadioButton(radioButt) {
    radioButt.prop("checked", true);
}
```

It is my first answer applied to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, use [ClientID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid(v=vs.110).aspx) to select the control with JQuery.
You must put the Jquery in your .aspx file.

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="Foo" runat="server" />
```

To select it with Jquery use:
 `$('#<%=Foo.ClientID%>')`

And if you want to do it in a more generic way read *Rick Sthrahl*'s post: [A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jquery](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2009/Oct/15/A-generic-way-to-find-ASPNET-ClientIDs-with-jquery)

Basically it boils down to:

```
function $$(id, context) {
    var el = $("#" + id, context);
    if (el.length < 1)
        el = $("[id$=_" + id + "]", context);
    return el;
}
```

In simple usage:

```
alert( $$("Foo").attr("id") );
```

Or if I want to be specific about the container:

```
alert( $$("Foo",$("#wrapper")).attr("id") );
```

Answer (score 0):

My main problem is, i cannot access the control id directly since i have to write generic function which should accept control id I am passing as parameter and there i should be able to retrieve and access it.

So i passed 'this.children' as parameter which sends childnodes collection of td.(in my page, radiobutton is always first child of td. so i can just pass 'this.children' as parameter in all onclick functions without specifying rdn btn id )
I retrieved it using   $('#' + tdchild[0].id).

```
<td  onclick="checkRadioButton(this.children);" >
     <asp:RadioButton ID="rdnQ10aOption1" runat="server" GroupName="Q10a"  />
     </td>

function checkRadioButton(tdchild) {
               $('#' + tdchild[0].id).prop("checked", true);
}
```